# amp-iframe JavaScript implementation

Tags: amp-html

I am running into some issues converting an existing page to comply with AMP-html. I am using amp's "iFrame" component so I can bring in a component that is standalone depending on its own JavaScript. The component is fully functional by itself, issue is when it gets iFramed in some of (or most of) the functionality does not work.

Is this going against AMP's guidelines? I can't seem to figure out the issue on my end, only idea is that it does not comply with AMP.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You either have your `amp-iframe` above the fold **without** a `placeholder` or you haven't allowed script execution in the `sandbox` attribute.

Add this to your `amp-iframe` element:

`sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"`

By default, [browsers block JS execution in iframes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox) That's why you must enable it with the `sandbox` attribute.